# Applescript to Map Esc to Caps Lock when tapped; Control to Caps Lock when pressed (macOS Sierra)?

Tags: applescript, custom-keyboard, macos-sierra, keyboard-maestro, karabiner

I am well aware of karabiner-elements which is still in development to enable this key mapping in macOS Sierra.  However, at the current moment it doesn't work.

My thought is that if I map Caps Lock to Control in Preferences/Keyboard/Modifier Keys that gets me half way there.  I have seen some interesting things people have done with AppleScript [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/how-do-i-automate-a-key-press-in-applescript). I am hoping there is a simple way to achieve this via AppleScript.  Its also worth mentioning that karabiner-elements is capable of swapping Caps Lock and Escape ([here](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner-Elements/tree/master/examples) are their examples).

Moreover, I tried to use Keyboard Maestro but my macro wouldn't recognize my Caps Lock key for my MacBook Pro 2015--I did set my Caps Lock to "No Action" in keyboard preferences, restarted, etc.  Below is a screenshot of what it should look like in Keyboard Maestro for reference.

In short, I tried everything and hope there is a simple solution to achieve this via AppleScript.  Thanks in advance.

[image: keyboard maestro caps lock key]

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try creating a [custom key binding file](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html), which works natively.

Also, [here is a helpful tool](https://web.archive.org/web/20171003175126/http://www.cocoabits.com:80/KeyBindingsEditor/) you can use to edit the key bindings file.

Hopefully that helps.