# Detecting & Setting Capslock in OSX Terminal

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, capslock

Is there a way to Detect If Capslock is On and then setting it Off (or reverse) from Terminal **without installing any extra software**?

Thanks a lot

Comment: See also this post on the Apple forums: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7094207

Comment: @PaulR - Debatable whether that's _"an exact duplicate of:..."_. The OP being tagged _bash/terminal_ seems to imply via the use of Bash (also states - _"...from Terminal "_), however the said _"exact duplicate of"_ asks specifically via use of _"Objective-C or C code"_.

Comment: @RobC: yes, I hadn't intended to use the "dupe hammer", just flag a number of possible duplicates (I had to add the other two in a comment - see above) - I'll re-open it for now, but I suspect the question will get closed anyway as it's way too vague and there is no evidence of any prior research effort.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [switch off caps lock programmatically macos](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54602097/253056); [Applescript to Map Esc to Caps Lock when tapped; Control to Caps Lock when pressed (macOS Sierra)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39736119/253056); [Simulate/Toggle CAPS LOCK programatically in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30035131/253056).

Comment: Cheers @PaulR for listening - appreciate that ;) Yes, I agree regarding reasons for closing.